# How to setup this home network to allow connection between two subnets?

Tags: router, networking, dhcp

I have my home network currently set up like this:

[image: My Home Network]

The Thomson router (192.168.0.1) is from my ISP and is pretty crappy. I have a much better Draytek Vigor 2820vn router that allows me to use things like VOIP etc and I much prefer using it.

My ISP has disabled the pass-through function on the Thomson router, and so I found the only way to send all the received internet packets to the Draytek, was to connect a cable to the Draytek's WAN2 port and put the Draytek into a DMZ.

[image: Thomsons DMZ settings]

The Draytek has been told that the WAN IP address is 192.168.0.2
[image: Draytek WAN setup]

And that its LAN IP address is 192.168.1.1
[image: Draytek LAN setup]

This has been working very well for the past year.

However I need to add more devices to my network, the Draytek now has no more ports, but the Thomson has 3 free. Another reason I would like to add some devices to the Thomson is because my ISP connection has now jumped to over 150MB  (excuse me if I have my Mb and MB incorrect here)

If I add another device to the Thomson, I can connect immediately to the internet with it. It gets assigned an IP address in the 192.168.0.xx range, **but I cannot connect in both directions with any device in the 192.168.1.xx range**.

So I'm sure I've set something up incorrectly. How/what should I do so that all devices can assess each other *no matter which subnet they are on* ie 192.168.0.xx/192.168.1.xx

(If I string another switch onto the end of my Draytek - I'll be limited to it's 100Mb ports. So I was hoping not to do that.)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to connect a consumer-grade ethernet switch to the LAN port of your Draytek router.

LAN switches will expand the number of ports available on 192.168.1.1/24; DHCP will pass seamlessly through the LAN switch to the Draytek.  Adding hosts on the Thompson router complicates things too much since you'll effectively have two gateways, and have to manage a additional static route on any PC you add on the Thompson.

Comment: The trouble is that the draytek only has 100Mb ports, I was hoping to utilise the 1GB ports on the Thomson. This is because my internet connection with my ISP is now 150Mb